# React-router: component undefined

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs, react-router

I've been running through the react-router tutorial found [here](https://github.com/rackt/react-router/blob/master/docs/guides/overview.md) and I'm currently puzzled...

React-router doesn't recognise my component.

(I'm using React.js with Rails)

[image]

Here's the code:

```
var DefaultRoute = ReactRouter.DefaultRoute;
var Link = ReactRouter.Link;
var Route = ReactRouter.Route;
var RouteHandler = ReactRouter.RouteHandler;

var App = React.createClass({

  getInitialState: function () {
    return {
      showTags: false,
      current_user: this.props.current_user
    };
  },

  _handleToggleTags: function() {
    this.setState({
      showTags: !this.state.showTags
    })
  },
  render: function () {
    return <div>
      <Header
        onToggleTags={ this._handleToggleTags }
        user={this.props.current_user}
      />

      <RouteHandler/>

      <div id="images">
          <ImageBox/>
      </div>
    </div>;
  }
});

var routes = (
  <Route name="app" path="/" handler={App}>
    <Route name="tags" handler={TagsBox}/>
  </Route>
);

ReactRouter.run(routes, function (Handler) {
  React.render(<Handler/>, document.body);
});
```

If I move TagsBox before App it works, though nobody else seems to be doing this. What am I missing?

If it makes a different, the current structure of my components is:

- app.js.jsx
- Tags

  - _tags_box.js.jsx

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "move TagsBox before App"? Is it defined in the same file? A Component being not defined sounds like a missing import.

Comment: Is your React library loaded on the browser via an script tag ?

Comment: @AdamStone - if I render the TagsBox class before the App class

Comment: @PhInside Yeah. it's included via the asset pipeline manifest file http://cl.ly/image/2g3W3k3d251m

Comment: Try to call the React library directly in your file. Maybe var React = require(react) I hope it will help.

Comment: @PhInside this doesn't really seem to fit in with the React-Rails way https://github.com/reactjs/react-rails

Answer (score 0):

In your position it seems best to run the router once all scripts are loaded.

Try wrapping the `run` method in this code:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  ReactRouter.run(routes, function (Handler) {
    React.render(<Handler/>, document.body);
  });
}
```

Comment: ideally though, you'll bite the bullet and try integrating a more modern asset pipeline base on e.g. webpack since it will help making dependencies much more explicit and offers a lot of niceties like e.g. hot code reloading etc